# is it possible to only update y-axis plot onclick?

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I'm using matplotlib to plot the specific values (x and y) from a numpy array list. I want to only edit the y-values while keeping the x-values the same (let's say only edit the y-value on click), but I can't seems to figure out how to.

I have tried

```py
def oncick(event):
    if event.button == 1:
        x.append(event.xdata)
        y.append(event.ydata)
    #clear frame
    plt.cla()
    plt.plot(x, y, linestyle = "-", lw= 5, color = "#FF4500")
    plt.draw()
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", onclick)
plt.show()
```

but it ends up redrawing from the latest x-axis (appending to add a new value)
and when I remove
`x.append(event.xdata)`
I got "ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension" error

Comment: what are some examples of data that you're starting with, and what data do you hope to have afterwards?

Comment: Data points are (x, y) couples. How exactly do you want to edit (append to?) only `y`? You cannot `plot(x, y)` if the arrays don't have the same size. If you want to save the y-value of where you clicked, what would be the associated x-value?

Comment: My data is pretty long but I'll get like a snippet of it. Let's say I have x = [0.0, 0.1, 0.2] and y [0.0, 124.793426, 110.961623] and I only want to edit the y value that associate with the x value depending on where I clicked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to append to your data or to clear the axes. We can create the data, create a line artist with your data and simply update everything upon click.

I am using `np.searchsorted` to find which index corresponds to where you clicked. Then, we change the `y` array at that index and replace the old value with the new value from the click event: `event.ydata`.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

x = np.arange(10)
y = np.sin(x)**2
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
line, = ax.plot(x, y, linestyle = "-", lw= 5, color = "#FF4500")

def on_click(event):
    if not event.inaxes: 
        return # Do nothing if the click is outside the ax.
    if event.button == 1:
        n = np.searchsorted(x, event.xdata)
        y[n] = event.ydata
        line.set_data(x, y)
        fig.canvas.draw()
    
fig.canvas.mpl_connect("button_press_event", on_click)
plt.show()
```

[image]

After a few clicks:

[image]

Comment: let's say is there any faster algorithm than `np.searchsorted()`? Because I also use this with on_move function on a really big number set and it lags out a lot

Comment: @Nevein I don't know about a faster function. Are you sure you need to use np.searchsorted for every mouse move events and every artist? I don't know what you do with that but there might be optimizations to find on your side too, not just on the side of the search algo.